# Foreign Key Constraint fail

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to insert a new row in the table but I'm getting below error:

```
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`wmetools_restool_dev/keywords`, CONSTRAINT `keywords_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`link_id`) REFERENCES `links` (`link_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

I have supplied all the fields required. Does it mean I need to insert more fields?

Comment: have you supplied `link_id`? post the `SHOW CREATE tbl_name` output for both tables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The table has a [foreign key contraint](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) to another table called `links`. You have to first insert a row in the `links` table with the correct `link_id` before you can insert the row into your table.